# Xamarin.iOS Custom View with class file VS2019 Version 16.9

Tags: xamarin.ios

Can anyone please guide me how to create a custom view in Xamarin.iOS using XCode.

[image]

Im trying to create a Custom Circular View with the class file. I was able to create a XIB file but not able to create a class file.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what do you need?

Answer (score 1):

To continue on what you did, do the following.

1. Create an empty class and name it CircularView

   ```
    public partial class CircularView : UIView
    {
        public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("CircularView");
        public static readonly UINib Nib;

        static CircularView()
        {
            Nib = UINib.FromName("CircularView", NSBundle.MainBundle);
        }

        protected CircularView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
            // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
        }

        public static CircularView CreateView()
        {
            return (CircularView)Nib.Instantiate(null, null)[0];
        }
    }
   ```
2. Create another class and name it CircularView.designer.cs

```
    [Register ("CircularView")]
     partial class CircularView
     {
        void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
        {
                    
        }
     }
```

3. Edit project file and add DependUpon tags like below

BEFORE

```
<Compile Include="Controls\CircularView.cs" />
<Compile Include="Controls\CircularView.designer.cs" />
```

AFTER

```
<Compile Include="Controls\CircularView.cs" />
<Compile Include="Controls\CircularView.designer.cs" >
    <DependentUpon>CircularView.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

this will ensure that VS shows the designer file as a child of CircularView.cs

4. where you want to use the new Custom view do the following

```
   var v = CircularView.CreateView();
   vwCustom.Add(v);
```

where vwCustom is a normal UIView added from Designer in my view controller, you can ofcourse name it anything.

Please let me know if you need further help.